# Vimeo video upload with title, description and more in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have to upload video on vimeo using vimeo API with title , description and more fields.

Currently I am using the official npm modules for vimeo video uploads from [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js).

I have used following code for uploading video , But in that we don't have any options to passed any `title` or `descriptions`.

```
        lib.streamingUpload('/home/aaron/Downloads/ada.mp4',  function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            lib.request(headers.location, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
                console.log(body);
            });
        }, function (upload_size, file_size) {
            console.log("You have uploaded " + Math.round((uploaded_size/file_size) * 100) + "% of the video");
        });
```

So please let me help me on how to passed other details with this npm module methods or any other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are sending Vimeo the video, receiving the response, and getting that video's metadata. Instead of receiving the video's metadata, you should edit it.

The documentation is [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D).

An example would look like this

```
lib.request('PATCH', headers.location, {
    title: "Your new title",
    description: "Your new description"
}, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did that